# Is there an option to find out spark internal table column values that has duplicate data

Tags: sql, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I am trying findout the rows in the spark internal table , where the **name** column  has duplicate data in it . For example consider the following data set , where the name column has repeated text coming in it .I am trying to find those rows and remove the duplicated data .

```
Input data
    Id   Name
    1    dil dil 
    2    lid
    3    tik tok
    4    tik tik 

Expected output data
    Id   Name
    1    dil 
    2    lid
    3    tik tok
    4    tik
```

But in some scenarios , I have certain names , which have 3 parts in it like below as well `abc  def  ghi`  . Which comes as `abc  def  ghi  abc def ghi`  . So I am not able to find a pattern in those scenario

Comment: what is the expected output on `word1 word2 word1` and  `word1 word2 word1 word2`? Or can we just assume it is two words max?

Comment: @Paul Thank you for the quick comment .I am trying to remove the duplicated /doubled names .In my scenario , certain names are coming twice .For example if you consider the name  `dileep vikram`  , it is coming as `dileep vikram dileep vikram` . I need to make the data as `dileep vikram`    .
But in some scenarios , I have certain names , which have 3 parts in it
like below as well 
`abc  def  ghi ` .
Which comes as `abc  def  ghi  abc def ghi ` .
So I am not able to find a pattern in those scenario

Comment: If there is a name like `dileep vikram dileep` the expected output should be `dileep vikram dileep` since the whole name `dileep vikram` is not repeated, right?  
The solution by @mck will output `dileep vikram` in that case and drop the second `dileep`. Also `dileep dileep vikram` will output `dileep vikram`

Comment: Your understanding of the requirement is correct .Will the update my question as well .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can match regex of repeating names and only extract the first occurence:

```
df.show(truncate=False)
+---+---------------------------+
|Id |Name                       |
+---+---------------------------+
|1  |dil dil                    |
|2  |lid                        |
|3  |tik tok                    |
|4  |tik tik                    |
|5  |dileep vikram dileep vikram|
|6  |abc def ghi abc def ghi    |
|7  |dileep vikram dileep       |
+---+---------------------------+

df.createOrReplaceTempView('df')
result = spark.sql(r"""
select Id, case when length(Name2) = 0 then Name else Name2 end Name
from (
    select Id, Name, regexp_extract(Name, '(.*)\\s+\\1+', 1) Name2
    from df
)
order by Id
""")

result.show()
+---+--------------------+
| Id|                Name|
+---+--------------------+
|  1|                 dil|
|  2|                 lid|
|  3|             tik tok|
|  4|                 tik|
|  5|       dileep vikram|
|  6|         abc def ghi|
|  7|dileep vikram dileep|
+---+--------------------+
```

Answer (score 1):

Supposing that words in Name column are sepparated by whitespace you can do it like this:

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as f


df.show(truncate=False)
+---+---------------------------+
|Id |Name                       |
+---+---------------------------+
|1  |dil dil                    |
|2  |lid                        |
|3  |tik tok                    |
|4  |tik tik                    |
|5  |dileep vikram dileep vikram|
|6  |abc def ghi abc def ghi    |
|7  |dileep vikram dileep       |
+---+---------------------------+

result = df.withColumn("Name", f.array_join(f.array_distinct(f.split(f.col("Name"), " "))), " ")

result.show()
+---+--------------------+
| Id|                Name|
+---+--------------------+
|  1|                 dil|
|  2|                 lid|
|  3|             tik tok|
|  4|                 tik|
|  5|       dileep vikram|
|  6|         abc def ghi|
|  7|dileep vikram dileep|
+---+--------------------+
```

These are the steps:

1. Put Name column as an array with words using split.
2. Delete duplicates with array_distinct.
3. Join words with array_join.